# Adding messages to inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this form and on it rows of inputs are added by the user with a j query function. I'm trying to add another j query function that checks to make sure that one of the inputs in the new rows is filled out before the next. Input-Status is dependent on input-type. Im trying to make so that when a user click son the status input before the type input they get a message telling them to fill the previous input first.
The function the adds the input rows:

```
var component_row = <?php echo $component_row; ?>;

function addComponents(language_id) {
    html  = '  <tr id="component-row' + component_row + '">';
  html += '  <td class="text-right"><input type="text" name="component_module[' + component_row + '][component_name]" value="" class="form-control" /></td>';
  html += '  <td class="text-right component-dropdown"><div class="component-dropdowns"> <select class="component_type_selection" name="component_module[' + component_row + '][component_type]" row_number="'+component_row+'" id="bobo'+component_row+'"><option value=""><?php echo $text_select; ?></option><option value="Email"><?php echo "Email" ?></option><option value="Text Message"><?php echo "Text Message" ?></option><option value="Direct Mail"><?php echo "Direct Mail" ?></option><option value="Transnational Email"><?php echo "Transnational Email" ?></option><option value="EVENT"><?php echo "Event" ?></option> </select><div></td>';
  html += '  <td class="text-right component-dropdown"><div class="component-dropdowns"> <select class="component_status_options" name="component_module[' + component_row + '][component_status]" row_number="'+component_row+'" id="list'+component_row+'"></select><p class="warning"></p><div> </td>';
  html += '  <td class="text-right component-dropdown"><div class="component-dropdowns"> <select name="component_module[' + component_row + '][component_owner]" ><option value=""><?php echo $text_select; ?></option><?php foreach ($users as $user) { ?><option value="<?php echo $user['username']; ?>" ><?php echo $user['username']; ?></option><?php } ?>  </select></div></td>';
  html += '  <td class="text-right" id="comp-cal"><div class="input-group date required"><input type="text" name="component_module[' + component_row + '][component_start_date]" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_date; ?>" data-date-format="YYYY-MM-DD"  class="form-control" /><span class="input-group-btn" id="component-calendar-btn">';
  html += '  <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button></span></div></td>';

  html += '  <td class="text-left"><button type="button" onclick="$(\'#component-row' + component_row + '\').remove();" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_remove; ?>" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></button></td>';
    html += '</tr>';

    $('#components tbody').append(html);
  $('.date').datetimepicker({
      formatDate:'yyyy-mm-dd',
      formatDate:'yyyy-mm-dd',
        pickTime: false
    });
    component_row++;
  }
```

The function Im trying to use to add the message

```
$( '.component_status_options').focus(function() {
$(this).siblings('p').text('Please select Type first')
});
```

html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> <?php echo $text_add_component; ?></h3>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body" id="addon">
            <div class=" col-lg-10 col-lg-push-1 form-group" >
              <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-special">
                <div class="table-responsive" id="component-module">
                  <table id="components" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <td class="text-left"><?php echo $entry_name; ?></td>
                        <td class="text-left"><?php echo $text_filter_type; ?></td>
                        <td class="text-left"><?php echo $entry_status; ?></td>
                        <td class="text-left"><?php echo $entry_owner; ?></td>
                        <td class="text-left"><?php echo $entry_component_start_date; ?></td>
                        <td></td>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      <?php $component_row = 0; ?>
                      <?php if(isset($component_modules)){ ?>
                        <?php foreach ($component_modules as $component_module) { ?>
                          <tr id="component-row<?php echo $component_row; ?>">
                            <td class="text-left"><input type="text"  name="component_module[<?php echo $component_row; ?>][component_name]" value="<?php echo $component_module['component_name']; ?>" class="form-control" /></td>

                            <td class="text-left"><input class="form-control" name="component_module[<?php echo $component_row; ?>][component_type]"value="<?php echo $component_module['component_type']; ?>"/ readonly></td>
                            <td class="text-left"><input class="form-control" name="component_module[<?php echo $component_row; ?>][component_status]"value="<?php echo $component_module['component_status']; ?>"/ readonly></td>

                            <td class="text-left"><div class="component-dropdowns"><select name="component_module[<?php echo $component_row; ?>][component_owner]" class="form-control"><?php foreach ($users as $user) { ?>
                              <option value="<?php echo $user['username']; ?>" <?php echo ($component_module['component_owner'] == $user['username']) ? 'selected' : ''; ?>><?php echo $user['username']; ?></option><?php } ?>  </select></div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="text-left"><div class="input-group date required"><input type="text" name="component_module[<?php echo $component_row; ?>][component_start_date]" value="<?php echo $component_module['component_start_date']; ?>" data-date-format="YYYY-MM-DD" class="form-control" /><span class="input-group-btn" id="component-calendar-btn"><button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button></span></div></td>
                            <input type="hidden"  name="component_module[<?php echo $component_row; ?>][component_parent_id]" value="<?php echo $component_module['parent_id']; ?>" class="form-control" />
                            <td class="text-left"><button type="button" onclick="$('#component-row<?php echo $component_row; ?>').remove();" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_remove; ?>" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></button></td>
                          </tr>


                          <?php $component_row++; ?>
                        <?php } ?>
                      <?php }else{ ?>
                      <tr>
                        <td colspan="5" class="text-center">No components </td>
                      </tr>
                    <?php } ?>

                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot>
                      <tr>
                        <td colspan="5"></td>
                        <td class="text-right"><button type="button"  onclick="addComponents();" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_add; ?>" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></button></td>
                      </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                  </table>
                    <?php if ($error_component_name) { ?>
                      <div class="text-danger"><?php echo $error_component_name; ?></div>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <?php if ($error_component_type) { ?>
                      <div class="text-danger"><?php echo $error_component_type; ?></div>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <?php if ($error_component_status) { ?>
                      <div class="text-danger"><?php echo $error_component_status; ?></div>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <?php if ($error_component_owner) { ?>
                      <div class="text-danger"><?php echo $error_component_owner; ?></div>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <?php if ($error_date_beginning) { ?>
                      <div class="text-danger"><?php echo $error_date_beginning; ?></div>
                    <?php } ?>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: can you paste the `html` of the page also?